# Response Keyword not Recognized

Tags: c#

i am trying to use commands like `Response.ClearContent()` and `Response.Write()` to export a datatable to Excel however visual studio is not recognizing the `Response` keyword. is there a `using` statment associated with these commands? Because i'm obviously missing something. thanks

Comment: There is no such keyword like `Response` in C#.

Comment: Response is [HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.100).aspx) in namespace System.Web, assembly System.Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is a property of type [HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) in the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class. `.ClearContent()` and `.Write()` are instance methods of type HttpResponse.

I cannot see how you expect to use this to write a *datatable to excel* (unless I am vastly overlooking something). By all means you could use Response to write the content of a datatable to a webpage, however to write to excel you may need a third party library, or some other functionality...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8411/C-class-library-for-exporting-data-to-CSV-Excel-fi

Comment: thanks very much for the feedback! i will try your codeproject solution now. :)

Comment: @ImanuelNimblett...it's not "MY" solution, just something I found on google! :-)

Comment: haha. THE (not yours) solution worked. lol. thanks again. it really helped me out. :D

Answer (score 3):

`Response` is simply a property of the [System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class (it's not a language keyword).  When you are writing code from a class that extends `Page` (which visual studio will do for .aspx files automatically) then `Repsonse` will be a valid instance field (you won't actually need any `using` statements to use it in this case).

If you aren't seeing it, then chances are you are writing code from a class that isn't extending `Page`.  You probably need to pass the response object (which is of type `System.Web.HttpResponse`) or the `HttpContext` (which has a referene to the response object) into the class that you are working with.  If you know that there is a valid HttpContext at the time the code is being executed it may also be an option to use `HttpContext.Current.Response` rather than passing the response via method parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot. i was going about the process all wrong. i just want to get my datatable into excel. its a wondows form application so there is no need for web related components.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the [`HttpResponse` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) in the [`System.Web`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspx) namespace.